# Can I import 3rd party package into golang playground

Tags: go, go-playground

I googled but got no answer. Is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

The Go Playground link: https://play.golang.org/

Comment: Currently, It's not possible.

Comment: Currently (May 2019, 4 years later)... it is possible! See [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27813778/6309).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since May 14th, 2019, [it is now possible](https://twitter.com/bradfitz/status/1128069715455123457) (from [Brad Fitzpatrick](https://twitter.com/bradfitz))!

> The #golang playground now supports third-party imports, pulling them in via https://proxy.golang.org/
>
> Example: https://play.golang.org/p/eqEo7mqdS9l
>
> Multi-file support & few other things up next.
> Report bugs at [`golang/go` issue 31944](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31944), or here on the tweeters.

(On the **"multiple file" support**, see, since May. 16th 2019, "[Which packages may be imported in the go playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56160948/6309)": see an [example here](https://play.golang.org/p/w3XRk47wo5u))

[netbrain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410747/netbrain) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812164/can-i-import-3rd-party-package-into-golang-playground/27813778?noredirect=1#comment98883929_27813778) another [example](https://play.golang.org/p/Hf5mQidVv5L):

On the playground:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat"
)

func main() {
    v1 := mat.NewVecDense(4,[]float64{1,2,3,4})
    fmt.Println(mat.Dot(v1,v1))
}
```

woud give '30', using [`mat.NewVecDense()`](https://godoc.org/gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat#NewVecDense) to create a column vector, and [`mat.Dot()`](https://godoc.org/gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat#Dot) to return the sum of the element-wise product of `v1` and `v1`

The point being: [`gonum/mat`](https://github.com/gonum/gonum/tree/master/mat) is *not* part of the [Go Standard Library](https://golang.org/pkg/).

---

Original answers:

The most complete article on Go Playground remains "[Inside the Go Playground](http://blog.golang.org/playground)", which mentions:

- [`godoc/static/static.go`](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/af7d92a90fbbc868c5d6cd4c3c9637637668d599/godoc/static/static.go#L511-L527) (for the default go program displayed in the playground)
- [`golang/tools/playground`](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/playground) for the sources, with [`playground/socket/socket.go`](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/playground/socket/socket.go#L237-L299) building and executing the program from the playground editor.

None of those processes support importing a remote package (that would be accessed over the internet).
It is very much a self-contained system (that you can run locally as well as using it from play.golang.org), with multiple features stubbed or faked, like the network:

> Like the file system, the playground's network stack is an in-process fake implemented by the syscall package.
> It permits playground projects to use the loopback interface (127.0.0.1).
> **Requests to other hosts will fail**.

---

Update 2017:

You have alternatives:

- [**`iafan/goplayspace`**](https://github.com/iafan/goplayspace)
- [**`xiam/go-playground`**](https://github.com/xiam/go-playground)

But they still use use the official Go Playground service to build and run Go code, so that would still not allow for external imports.

Comment: @netbrain Thank you. I have included your example in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it myself but [xiam/go-playground](https://github.com/xiam/go-playground) indicates that this is possible:

> **Importing custom packages**
>
> Remember that playground users won't be able to install or use packages that are not part of the Go standard library, in case you want to showcase a special package you'll have to create a slightly different docker image on top of the sandbox or the unsafebox...

(Followed by example of how to do this with a Dockerfile modification.)

This would seem to indicate that the compilation is (or at least can be) performed inside a custom sandbox as show in the xiam/go-playground project, thus making this possible (not requiring play.golang.org as indicated by @VonC's answer).

If I get a chance to test this myself I'll update this answer with more detail.