# Which packages may be imported in the go playground?

Tags: go, go-playground

I had trouble finding a list of what packages may be imported in the go playground at http://play.golang.org/. I was trying to use the (apparently experimental) package for [ebnf](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/exp/ebnf). However even a short program won't import from `golang.org` (breaks on the import on line 4):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "golang.org/x/exp/ebnf"

const g = `
Production  = name "=" [ Expression ] "." .
Expression  = Alternative { "|" Alternative } .
Alternative = Term { Term } .
Term        = name | token [ "…" token ] | Group | Option | Repetition .
Group       = "(" Expression ")" .
Option      = "[" Expression "]" .
Repetition  = "{" Expression "}" .`

func main() {
    fmt.Println(g)
}
```

Is it stated anywhere that only base packages in [golang.org/src/](https://golang.org/src/) would import (if that's the case)?

I'd really like to play with this experimental package and even non-experimental supplemental libraries like [`currency`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/currency) in the playground.

Comment: "The playground can use most of the standard library, with some exceptions." Well, less than stdlib, then ;)

Comment: BTW Thanks to all; of course I'd read the about. I says it what everyone says it says. It doesn't seem to say exactly what "most" is, nor that anything that is not in the standard library cannot be used. The blog post about it does helpfully point out some areas where standard library behavior is different than normal. I appreciate the more complete list, based on a test, provided in the answer.

Comment: You can add the list of packages of GOPROXY now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27813778/6309

Comment: @VonC yes, this question is quite dated compared to updates to the playground.

Comment: @dlamblin I have added [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56160948/6309) to point out that you can import your *own* package now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The <kbd>About</kbd> button on the Playground gives some hint:

> The playground can use most of the standard library, with some exceptions.

By the *standard library* the packages of the *standard library* are meant, which are listed on the [**Packages**](https://golang.org/pkg/) page, under the [**Standard library**](https://golang.org/pkg/#stdlib) section. Packages listed under the [**Other**](https://golang.org/pkg/#other) section do not qualify (which is what you have tried - package [`golang.org/x/exp/ebnf`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/exp/ebnf) falls under the experimental and deprecated packages listed under the **Other** category).

A must-read link if you want to know more about the Playground implementation:

[**The Go Blog: Inside the Go Playground**](https://blog.golang.org/playground)

Here is an exhaustive playground test to import all the standard library packages to show they at least can be imported, but that doesn't mean everything (*or even anything*) can be reasonably used from them. The only package from the standard library that gives a compile error is `runtime/cgo`; "packages" without a buildable Go source file are not included for obvious reasons (because a folder is [not a package](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages) if it does not contain at least one buildable Go source file).

Here's the [Playground Link](http://play.golang.org/p/YcdVP6e76s) to try it yourself.

```
package main

import (
    _ "archive/tar"
    _ "archive/zip"

    _ "bufio"
    _ "bytes"

    _ "compress/bzip2"
    _ "compress/flate"
    _ "compress/gzip"
    _ "compress/lzw"
    _ "compress/zlib"

    _ "container/heap"
    _ "container/list"
    _ "container/ring"

    _ "crypto"
    _ "crypto/aes"
    _ "crypto/cipher"
    _ "crypto/des"
    _ "crypto/dsa"
    _ "crypto/ecdsa"
    _ "crypto/elliptic"
    _ "crypto/hmac"
    _ "crypto/md5"
    _ "crypto/rand"
    _ "crypto/rc4"
    _ "crypto/rsa"
    _ "crypto/sha1"
    _ "crypto/sha256"
    _ "crypto/sha512"
    _ "crypto/subtle"
    _ "crypto/tls"
    _ "crypto/x509"
    _ "crypto/x509/pkix"

    _ "database/sql"
    _ "database/sql/driver"

    _ "debug/dwarf"
    _ "debug/elf"
    _ "debug/gosym"
    _ "debug/macho"
    _ "debug/pe"
    _ "debug/plan9obj"

    _ "encoding"
    _ "encoding/ascii85"
    _ "encoding/asn1"
    _ "encoding/base32"
    _ "encoding/base64"
    _ "encoding/binary"
    _ "encoding/csv"
    _ "encoding/gob"
    _ "encoding/hex"
    _ "encoding/json"
    _ "encoding/pem"
    _ "encoding/xml"

    _ "errors"
    _ "expvar"
    _ "flag"
    _ "fmt"

    _ "go/ast"
    _ "go/build"
    _ "go/constant"
    _ "go/doc"
    _ "go/format"
    _ "go/importer"
    _ "go/parser"
    _ "go/printer"
    _ "go/scanner"
    _ "go/token"
    _ "go/types"

    _ "hash"
    _ "hash/adler32"
    _ "hash/crc32"
    _ "hash/crc64"
    _ "hash/fnv"

    _ "html"
    _ "html/template"

    _ "image"
    _ "image/color"
    _ "image/color/palette"
    _ "image/draw"
    _ "image/gif"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    _ "image/png"

    _ "index/suffixarray"

    _ "io"
    _ "io/ioutil"

    _ "log"
    _ "log/syslog"

    _ "math"
    _ "math/big"
    _ "math/cmplx"
    _ "math/rand"

    _ "mime"
    _ "mime/multipart"
    _ "mime/quotedprintable"

    _ "net"
    _ "net/http"
    _ "net/http/cgi"
    _ "net/http/cookiejar"
    _ "net/http/fcgi"
    _ "net/http/httptest"
    _ "net/http/httputil"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    _ "net/mail"
    _ "net/rpc"
    _ "net/rpc/jsonrpc"
    _ "net/smtp"
    _ "net/textproto"
    _ "net/url"

    _ "os"
    _ "os/exec"
    _ "os/signal"
    _ "os/user"

    _ "path"
    _ "path/filepath"

    _ "reflect"
    _ "regexp"
    _ "regexp/syntax"

    _ "runtime"
    // _ "runtime/cgo"  // ERROR: missing Go type information
                        // for global symbol: .dynsym size 60
    _ "runtime/debug"
    _ "runtime/pprof"
    _ "runtime/race"
    _ "runtime/trace"

    _ "sort"
    _ "strconv"
    _ "strings"
    _ "sync"
    _ "sync/atomic"
    _ "syscall"

    _ "testing"
    _ "testing/iotest"
    _ "testing/quick"

    _ "text/scanner"
    _ "text/tabwriter"
    _ "text/template"
    _ "text/template/parse"

    _ "time"
    _ "unicode"
    _ "unicode/utf16"
    _ "unicode/utf8"
    _ "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    println("ok")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I had trouble finding a list of what packages may be imported in the go playground at http://play.golang.org/. 2022: https://go.dev/play/

Finding an exact list will be all the more difficult than you now (May. 16th 2019)

- can [import any package referenced by `GOPROXY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27813778/6309)
- can import your *own* package (defined in the "play.ground") namespace.
  See the [announcement from Brad Fitzpatrick](https://twitter.com/bradfitz/status/1128747022503165952)

> And now the #golang playground has support for multiple files: [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/KLZR7NlVZNX)

[Dmitri Shuralyov adds](https://twitter.com/dmitshur/status/1128817738678448128):

> Which means you can also have multiple modules! And `go.mod` files get formatted now too: [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/w3XRk47wo5u)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopher.example/bar"
    "play.ground/foo"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(foo.Bar)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(bar.Baz)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("And go.mod files get formatted too. Try pressing the Format button!")
}
-- go.mod --

  module      "play.ground"

   replace (

       "gopher.example/bar"    => ./bar
 )

-- foo/foo.go --
package foo

const Bar = "The Go playground now has support for multiple files!"
-- bar/go.mod --
module gopher.example/bar
-- bar/bar.go --
package bar

const Baz = "Which means you can have multiple modules too!"
```

- March 2022: **can select between the most recent Go versions** (see [`golang/go` issue 33629](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33629#issuecomment-1072650987)):
  1.17, 1.18 or dev version.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to depend on the environment in which the playground is launched.  The relevant code in the source seems to be the [`compileAndRun`](https://github.com/golang/playground/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox.go#L67-L89) func, especially line 88:

```
cmd.Env = []string{"GOOS=nacl", "GOARCH=amd64p32", "GOPATH=" + os.Getenv("GOPATH")}
```

Which gets the GOPATH from the environment.

Other than that, the playground source does not have any explicit whitelist (or blacklist) of importable packages.

It's probably key to note that the `compileAndRun` func has no code to `go get` packages, so whatever is already in the GOPATH is what is available.

A perusal of the Makefile and Dockerfile does not reveal the specific deployment steps taken in the canonical http://play.golang.org site, so we simply have to rely on the documentation that Markus W Mahlberg pointed out; i.e. "a subset of the stdlib".

Also, you can deploy your own version of the go playground, and give it whatever GOPATH environment you choose.