# How can I import a library from github to GO playground?

Tags: go, docker, go-playground

Hi I want to import a 3rd party library to GO playground, I saw an answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27813778/6638204 but it said that this can not be done, but the [xiam/go-playground](https://github.com/xiam/go-playground) library on github states that it can do this. I tried using it but I did not understand what should I exactly do. I successfully installed the library and used it to run programs that do not need third party libraries. but I did not get how can I import a third party library. ps: I have docker installed in my machine

Comment: So your question is: "How do I use xiam/go-playground?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I import 3rd party package into golang playground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812164/can-i-import-3rd-party-package-into-golang-playground)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is still the same: you can't do that on the "official" Go Playground (at https://play.golang.org/).

If you or someone else runs a custom, modified version of the Go Playground: then the answer is you can do there whatever is allowed, which may include the usage of external libraries which the custom engine may `go get` prior to compilation and execution.

Also see related question: [Which packages may be imported in the go playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409302/which-packages-may-be-imported-in-the-go-playground)

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do it since May 14th, 2019

See [this tweet](https://twitter.com/bradfitz/status/1128069715455123457) (from [Brad Fitzpatrick](https://twitter.com/bradfitz))!

> The #golang playground now supports third-party imports, pulling them in via https://proxy.golang.org/
>
> Example: https://play.golang.org/p/eqEo7mqdS9l
>
> Multi-file support & few other things up next.
> Report bugs at [`golang/go` issue 31944](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31944), or here on the tweeters.

But that means you have published your package deliverable in such a way it is reference by [the Go proxy](https://twitter.com/FiloSottile/status/1123325054794657792).